# Does Visual Studio 2008 Express support t4?

Tags: visual-studio, t4, visual-studio-express, t4mvc

I'm trying to use [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC&referringTitle=Documentation) in [Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) and it's not building any files.  Is [T4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit) supported in the express editions?

Comment: Not building? Could do with error output then.

Comment: @Lee, no error, just no files are created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I talked to the T4 expert, and he confirmed that 2008 Express indeed does *not* support T4.  He referred to it as a bug, so apparently it wasn't a deliberate design choice, but more something that was not intended.

The good news is that this should be fixed is VS 2010 Express, which is getting pretty close to being released.

Comment: Thanks David.  I like your blog, and look forward to using T4MVC.

Comment: See this question for the status of T4 support in VS 2010 Express: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309551/does-vs-2010-express-edition-support-t4-preprocessed-templates