# I'd like a preprocessing language for metaprogramming

Tags: c#, .net, templates, metaprogramming, preprocessor-meta-program

I'm looking for a language sort of like PHP, but more brief -- I'm tempted to call it a "templating engine" but I'm pretty sure that's the wrong term. What is the right term? A text preprocessor?

Anyway I'd like it to be .NET-based because I want to use it to help write .NET code. Because .NET generics are unsuited for writing fast numeric code ([the known workaround](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/genericnumerics.aspx) is too cumbersome and limited for my needs), I'd like to write a math library using some sort of preprocessing language that allows me to output C# code. For example, I'd like to generate a series of "Point" classes made from various data types (PointF, PointD, PointI, etc.):

```
#foreach(($T, $Type) in {(F, float), (D, double), (I, int), ...}) #{
    public struct Point$T {
        public $Type X, Y;
        ...
    }
#}
```

What can you fine people suggest?

Comment: "A LISP"? ;-) I thought that .NET generics of value-types (when not running through boxing issues) where supposed to be very fast after their run-time specialization and JIT'ing (as opposed to Java/JVM which has no run-time specialization and only has boxed types for "generic" primitives).

Comment: Generics of value types are fast for purposes such as lists or dictionaries. However, a generic type cannot perform calculations on value types such as adding T + T together. I'm writing a math library so I'll be doing TONS of math on type T.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you had a chance to try T4 templates?   That should be sufficient for what you are trying to achieve.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Comment: Wow, I certainly didn't expect this to be built-in! I'm using C# Express so here's an obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309551/does-vs-2010-express-edition-support-t4-preprocessed-templates

Answer (score 1):

The [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) code generation and templating engine comes with Visual Studio.

- [Understanding T4: Preprocessed Text Templates](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/09/t4-preprocessed-text-templates/)

There's also [String Template](http://www.stringtemplate.org/), which has a C# port.