# Do Visual Studio 2012 express editions support T4 templates?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, t4

Which Visual Studio 2012 express editions support T4 templates?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, VS has supported T4 since shortly after VS2005 and has built-in since then.

Also here's someone from [VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309551/does-vs-2010-express-edition-support-t4-preprocessed-templates) letting you know issues with 2010's express not showing t4 by default, even though it is there and works.

One way that should work to tell is to create a new text file, and end it with `.tt`, see if you get a VS solution explorer icon immediately showing it would generate something.  If not try setting the custom tool property of that file to `TextTemplatingFileGenerator`

[*2005: Microsoft released the first version of T4 as an out of band release for Visual Studio 2005*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit)